# Is $C_1 + C_2$ closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Two questions jump into my mind when I was working with cone, I feel they are very related to each other. one I asked here
"[Is $T(C) \subseteq R^m$ closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3272934/219176)"

Second one is: If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two closed, convex cone in $R^n$ then 
is $$C_1 + C_2  = \{c_1 + c_2 \; | \;  c_1 \in C_1 , ~ c_2 \in C_2\} $$

a closed set?

The answer for my first question is No, I feel the answer of my second question is No as well but I dont have an explicit example to confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, a counter-example.

Let $C_1$ be the closed convex cone $x^2+y^2\leq z^2$, $z\geq 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $C_2$ be the half-line $t(1,0,-1)$, $t\geq 0$.

Then $C_1+C_2=\operatorname{conv}(C_1\cup C_2)$ does not contain $(0,1,0)$, but it contains
$$
\overbrace{(-t,1+t^{-1},t + \frac{t^{-1} + 2t^{-2} + t^{-3}}2)}^{\in C_1}+\overbrace{(t,0,-t)}^{\in C_2}=(0,1+t^{-1},\frac{t^{-1} + 2t^{-2} + t^{-3}}2)
$$
for all $t\gg 1$.

Comment: I dont agree ! How does the compactness of $(C_1\cap\bar B)+(C_2\cap\bar B)$ imply the closedness of $C_1 + C_2$?

Comment: Take the closed ball centered $(0,1)$ with radius $r=1$ in $R^2$, and think about the cone generated by that.

Comment: Right, wasn't thinking straight.  Cooked up a counterexample.

Comment: Nice Example, Thank you.

Comment: Nice counterexample, +1, but how on earth did you come up with that formula for points that get arbitrarily close to $(0,1,0)$? What was the thought process that led you to that expression?

Comment: @J_P It is the same rotation idea as with the $T(C)$ not closed example that leads to trying $(1,0,-1)$-cone/ray and $(0,1,0)$.  At first I use $\sqrt{t^2+(1+1/t)^2}$ for $z$ in the cone, then note it can be approximated.

Comment: Ah, so $(t,1-t^{-1},\sqrt{t^2+1+t^{-2}})$ works and then you get rid of the root. Am I getting this right?

Comment: yes, that works.  It isn't necessary to remove the roots, it just looks nicer :-)