# Show that the set $\{Ax|x\in C\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to proof the statement below:

Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and a closed set $C \subset R^n$, show that the set $\{Ax, x \in C\}$ is closed.

However, I am not able to proof that statement.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Ow, so how can I prove it to be true? Now I'm even more lost lol. I edited the post :)

Comment: I apologize for  my misleading comment earlier.  Here is a counter-example. Let $C=\{(x,y): xy=1\}$. This set is closed. Let $A$ be the matrix corresponding to the projection map $(x,y) \to x$. Then the image is $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ which is not closed.

Comment: Oh, do not worry. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the example from [this great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497944/a-linear-transform-of-a-closed-set-is-closed). Choose
$$
C = \{(x, y) : y \ge e^x\}\subset \mathbb R^2
$$
so that $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. [You will want to actually prove that this set is closed, which is time consuming, but not difficult.] Let $A$ be the transformation given by the matrix (with respect to the standard basis)
$$
A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Notice what $A$ does to a point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ y \end{pmatrix}
$$
That is, $A$ is the projection onto the $y$-axis. It does not take a bit of thought to see that $AC= \{A x \colon x \in C\}$ is the set $\{(0,y) \colon y \in (0,\infty) \}$. But this set is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For instance, the point $(0,0) \notin AC$ but every open neighborhood of $(0,0)$ contains points of $AC$. The result is true if we choose the transformation $A$ to be invertible. See the solution linked.